# sql scripts in vba

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am having trouble running my sql code in a for loop. The code works for simple pasting the the sql code in one sheet but not when i put it in a loop. Does anyone have some experience in positing sql scripts in a for loop.

I need it to loop over my three sheets and paste the sql code in each sheet.

```
Sub rapport()

Dim ws_count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim fundowner(3) As String



fundowner(1) = "110"
fundowner(2) = "120"
fundowner(3) = "130"
'fundowner(4) = "110"
'fundowner(5) = "110"


' Set variables
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs_set As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String
 
'Set Connection
 Set rs_set = New ADODB.Recordset
 Set con = New ADODB.Connection

    con.ConnectionString = NPARRP_CONN_STRING
    con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    con.Open

'Sheets("Ark1").Select
'Range("A9:I1000").ClearContents
'sql = Sheets("Ark1").Cells(1, 1).Value

sql = "Select  port.FUND_OWNER, sum(fig.ASSETS)" & _
"from SCDDEX.NP_DM_FUND_FIGURES_V fig" & _
"inner join SCDDEX.NP_DM_FUND_PORTFOLIO_DEX port on fig.POR=PORT.POR" & _
"where port.FUND_OWNER in('130')" & _
"and DATE_FOR_FIGURES='2019-11-04'" & _
" group by port.FUND_OWNER"


ws_count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For i = 1 To ws_count
    
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(1, 1) = fundowner(i) Then
            
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(3, 1) = sql
            
            Debug.Print sql

            rs_set.Open sql, con

            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(9.1).CopyFromRecordset rs_set
        Else
        
            MsgBox "Error"
        
       End If
        
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the Source string for the SQL connection on every iteration to output the recordset according to your `fundownder` value.

Keep in mind that by this approach, fundowner has be dimensioned according to the number of sheets in the workbook.

Also you will have to Close the recordset each time.

```
Sub rapport()

Dim ws_count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim fundowner(1 To 3) As String

fundowner(1) = "110"
fundowner(2) = "120"
fundowner(3) = "130"

' Set variables
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs_set As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String
 
'Set Connection
Set rs_set = New ADODB.Recordset
Set con = New ADODB.Connection

con.ConnectionString = NPARRP_CONN_STRING
con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
con.Open


ws_count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To ws_count

        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(1, 1) = fundowner(i) Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(3, 1) = sql

            sql = "Select  port.FUND_OWNER, sum(fig.ASSETS) " & _
                  "from SCDDEX.NP_DM_FUND_FIGURES_V fig " & _
                  "inner join SCDDEX.NP_DM_FUND_PORTFOLIO_DEX port on fig.POR=PORT.POR " & _
                  "where port.FUND_OWNER ='" & fundowner(i) & "') " & _
                  "and DATE_FOR_FIGURES='2019-11-04' " & _
                  "group by port.FUND_OWNER"
            
            Debug.Print sql

            rs_set.Open sql, con

            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Cells(9.1).CopyFromRecordset rs_set

            rs_set.Close
        Else
        
            MsgBox "Error"
        
       End If
Next i

End Sub
```